# Is it possible to specify an at command on a single line?

Tags: command-line, at

I'd like to schedule 8 curl commands over the next 12 hours. I was wondering if there's a way to do with with 8 single-line calls to at. Sorta like:

```
$  at now + 1 min "curl -X POST 'http://localhost:5566/export/778'"
```

or

```
$ at now + 1 min -- curl -X POST 'http://localhost:5566/export/778'
```

But neither of those work. I don't see anything in the man page about this.

Barring that, is there a way to set the time for the next command while inside the `at` subshell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A portable way is:

```
$ echo "curl -X POST 'http://localhost:5566/export/778'" | at now + 1 min
```

Answer (score 5):

You should be using here string:

```
$ at now + 1 min <<<"curl -X POST 'http://localhost:5566/export/778'"
```